# write single SQLquery if possible?

Tags: mysql, oracle10g

There are three tables (column names are in brackets):

- 1-user_table (user_id, social_site)

  - value in social_site -> fb, whatsapp, wechat
- 2-booking_confirm (booking_id)
- 3-payment_table (order_id, payment_status)

  - payment_status = "success" or "fail"

---

```
no of user |  social site |   no of payment successful
34         |  fb          |   10
```

"no of user": find count(user_id) with respect to "fb" and "payment" (when order_id = booking_id and payment_status="success")

Answer (score 0):

There's no connection between USER_TABLE (your first table) and another two tables, so the following query certainly won't work, but might give you an idea of how to do it (once you manage to fix what's wrong).

```
select count(*)
from user_table u join ??? on ???                  --> what goes here?
--
booking_confirm b join payment_table p on b.booking_id = p.order_id
where u.social_site = 'fb'
  and p.payment_status = 'success'
```

Comment: no of user and no of payment both are calculated respect to social site

Comment: OK, but you can't do that if USER_TABLE can't be joined to other tables. Currently, with information you provided so far, it can not (or, if it can, I don't see how).

Comment: There many city and college and class
            This University table we get from SQL query

            City  |College | Class

            KANPUR | ABC    | CS-A
            KANPUR | ABC    | CS-B
            KANPUR | ABC    | EC-A
            Delhi  | Deep   | ME-A

            I store data in array format and for each through i print
            and we have show in view page
            In code  like : $CITY '-' $COLL '(CS)'
             KANPUR -  ABC(CS) //NO NEED TO BOTH CS-A AND CS-B 
             KANPUR -  ABC(EC) //Take either A OR B tell how to ask question in stack